# Magento 2 use custom data in ui component

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent

I'm adding a custom UiComponent to checkout using Layout Processor:

1. LayoutProcessor.php

```php
$this->jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']
['children']['summary']['children'] = [
'my-item' => [
    'displayArea' => 'my-item',
    'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/view/my-item',
    'config' => [
        'template' => 'Vendor_Module/my-item'
    ],
    'custom-data' => 'some custom data' 
];
```

2. Vendor_Module/js/view/my-item.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function ($, ko, Component, totals) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            items: ko.observable([]),
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                totals.getItems().subscribe(function (items) {
                    this.setItems(items);
                }.bind(this));
            },
            getItemsToRender: function () {
                `I want my custom data here`
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Is it possible to "send" custom data from LayoutProcessor to js component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `config` as an argument in your `initialize` method:

```
initialize: function (config) {
    this._super();
    totals.getItems().subscribe(function (items) {
        this.setItems(items);
    }.bind(this));

    console.log(config)
}
```

I have only done this with x-magento-init and not PHP Layout Processors but I'm hoping it works the same.

If it works it will likely only return the template as that's all you have in your config, but you will be able to move your custom data inside the config if that is the case.

Comment: thanks, I added my custom data under 'config' in PHP Layout Processors and it worked.

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help.